# Why doesn't Tesseract detect punctuation in English?

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to build an app in Android using Tesseract for character recognition. The app detects the words correctly but does not detect any of the punctuation marks. For example, if I take a picture of a the sentence "The , Little Boy ", the output I get is " The Little Boy " (the "" are not part of the input nor the output). How can I make Tesseract see the punctuation marks?

Comment: Have you checked your white and black list of characters?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you call Tesseract, maybe you are using a wrong mode?

Comment: This could be worth a look: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-issues/e2RcvrTAAnE